# When the permutation representation $k\Omega$ of a finite set $\Omega$ is semisimple, under the transitive action of a finite group.

Tags: representation-theory, group-actions, semi-simple-rings

I am struggling to fully understand and tackle the following exercise:

> If $G$ is a finite group acting transitively on a finite set $\Omega$, then the permutation representation $k\Omega$, with $\mathrm{char}k = p$, is a semisimple $kG$-module if and only if $p\nmid |\Omega|$.

Now, from Wikipedia I gather that the permutation representation is the pair $(k\Omega,\rho)$ with $\rho:G\rightarrow \mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$, and extended to be $k$-linear.

I see that the transitivity of the action of $G$ implies that the action is fully determined by its effect on any one element of $\Omega$ - does this imply that $G$ is cyclic?

For the 'only if' direction, I believe I need to assume $p\mid |\Omega|$, and construct a submodule without complement, to contradict complete reducibility. Not sure how, though.

I have no idea how to deal with the 'if' direction.

I feel I am missing some important idea on how to use all this finiteness.

Note: this is at the beginning of a course in Representation Theory, hence there is not much machinery - I can't see how to use the Jordan-Hölder Theorem, the Schur's lemma does not apply; maybe I need to look at the central characters of $k\Omega$..?

Comment: 1. No, transitivity doesn't imply that $G$ is cyclic, e.g. every finite group acts transitively on itself by left multiplication. 2. Start with the action of a cyclic group of order $p$ on itself to get your bearings.

Comment: Another good place to start would just be considering the action of the symmetric group $S_3$ on the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$. In characteristic zero, there is an obvious one-dimensional subspace, and an obvious complement (think about the dot product). What happens in characteristic 3?

Comment: Have you heard of Maschke's Theorem? That will handle the "only if" part.